# I want to change the width of textfield dynamically on button click

Tags: java

The code inside constructor is:

```
{
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.add(txt);
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("change");
    jp.add(btn1);
}
```

I'm just stuck in my `actionPerformed` method. What can i code here?

Comment: Have you looked at the JTextField class? go there. Google 'JTextField java' You'll find it. Do research before coming to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In anonymous block you've to set the size of text field.

```
 JButton btnChangeWidth = new JButton("Change width");
 btnChangeWidth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         textField.setSize(x, y);

     }
 });
```

don't forget to add the button on container..

for more reference you can visit here http://cshotopics.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-change-width-of-textfield.html

Comment: i visited your link and yes it really helped me but as you mentioned in your topic what is the meant of               EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {       // code    });                                                                  the code inside your main method..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched Java Swing for years, but have you tried something like this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     int currentCols = txt.getColumns();
     txt.setColumns(currentCols + 5);
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is increasing the columns of the JTextBox by 5, everytime the button is clicked

I'm not sure if this works, but I hope I helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can change size using this method  `txt.setColumns(yourNewSize);`

Answer (score 0):

If you go like:

```
((the JFrames name) if do not extend JFrame).setLayout(null);
```

Then Im pretty sure you can simply go:

```
txt.setSize(newSizeX, newSizeY) //in pixels
```

whenever you press the button.